# Mocking useFormikContext<T>() Hook in TypeScript using React-Testing-Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, react-hooks, jestjs

I'm having a tough time trying to get the react-hooks library to work with Formik - specifically `useFormikContext<FormTypeFields>()` - in TypeScript in my project.  I have fields where I want to test the ability to automatically type into them inside of react-testing-library.  Right now I think I'm getting somewhere, but the `result.current` inside of the act function is undefined.  I've attached sample code that I hope will help.

*TestForm.tsx*

```
import React from "react";
import { Grid, GridItem } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { FormTypeFields } from "./form-type-fields.model";

const TestForm = () => {
  const { values } = useFormikContext<FormTypeFields>();
  const { testField } = values;

  return (
    <Grid
      templateColumns="repeat(12, minmax(0, 1fr))"
      gap={{ base: 6, md: 8, lg: 8 }}
    >
      <GridItem colSpan={12}>
        <label for="testField">Test Field</label>
        <input type="text" id="testField" name="testField" />
      </GridItem>
    </Grid>
  );
}

export default TestForm;
```

*form-type-fields.model*

```
export class FormTypeFields {
  testField: string = "";

  constructor(entity: any) {
    if (!entity) return;
    this.testField = entity.testField;
  }
}
```

Here's the test I'm trying to write:
*TestForm.test.tsx*

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import TestForm from "./TestForm";
import * as Formik from "formik";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import { renderHook, act } from "@testing-library/react-hooks";
import { FormTypeFields } from "./test-form-fields.model";

describe("typing should work", async () => {
  const { result } = renderHook<
    Formik.FormikContextType<FormTypeFields>,
    Formik.FormikContextType<FormTypeFields>
  >(() => Formik.useFormikContext<FormTypeFields>());

  act(() => {
    result.current.values = { testField: "" };
  });

  render(<TestForm />);

  expect(screen).toMatchSnapshot();
  await userEvent.keyboard("ABC");
  expect(screen.getByLabelText("Test Field").innerHTML).toContain("ABC");
});
```

I can't figure out how to wire this up so I can test the `keyboard("ABC")` function in the react-testing-library functionality on the input form.

The error message is this:

```
    TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'values')

      15 |
      16 |   act(() => {
    > 17 |     result.current.values = { testField: "" };
         |     ^
      18 |   });
      19 |
      20 |   render(<TestForm />);
```

And I'm getting this warning:

```
console.warn
    Warning: Formik context is undefined, please verify you are calling useFormikContext() as child of 
a <Formik> component.

      11 |     Formik.FormikContextType<FormTypeFields>,
      12 |     Formik.FormikContextType<FormTypeFields>
    > 13 |   >(() => Formik.useFormikContext<FormTypeFields>());
         |                  ^
      14 |
      15 |   act(() => {
      16 |     result.current.values = { testField: "" };
```

Looking for suggestions, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer.  All you need to do is add the FormikProvider and Formik tags inside of the render.

```
render(
  <FormikProvider value={...}>
    <Formik initialValues={...} onSubmit={...}>
      <TestForm />
    </Formik>
  </FormikProvider>
);
```